# Swift 4, Simultaneous access to tuple members as inout

Tags: swift

Why do i get `Simultaneous accesses to 0x108ce0000`?

```
func swapInts(_ a: inout Int, _ b: inout Int) {
   let temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}

var Ints = (first:2, second:3);
swapInts(&Ints.first, &Ints.second);
print(Ints);
```

How one passes Tuple members by inout/reference in swift?

`swift --version` is `Apple Swift version 4.0 (swiftlang-900.0.52 clang-900.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9`[image]

Comment: This is not the actual code that caused the error. Your code causes no problem.

Comment: @matt I read your answer that you now have deleted, yes it is swift 4.
It was the right answer i think, why did you delete it?

Comment: Because your code causes no error. Ask the question more carefully.

Comment: @matt It does on my machine, swift --version is "Apple Swift version 4.0 (swiftlang-900.0.52 clang-900.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9"

Comment: Your code never even calls `swapInts`. So why are you showing it?

Comment: @matt I'm really sorry, updated the code. I still get the same error.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. What I'm saying in my deleted answer may be right but I need a reproducible example in order to have something to talk about.

Comment: @matt Thanks again, added an screenshot. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The fact that I can't reproduce it in an actual app project is weird, and may be a bug.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simultaneous access is a new Swift 4 issue. Watch the WWDC video discussion of *exclusive access*, which is now being enforced. (Or read the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md) on swift-evolution.)

The exclusive access rule is there to prevent you *exactly* from doing what you're trying to do. You must not use `inout` to access things like multiple elements of an Array, a struct and its property, or (as you have discovered) the elements of a tuple — because the results can be incoherent.

Thus, this would be legal:

```
var Ints = (first:2, second:3);
var i = 4
swapInts(&Ints.first, &i);
```

But what you have is not:

```
var Ints = (first:2, second:3);
swapInts(&Ints.first, &Ints.second);
```

This case is pretty simple, though; there is no need to pass both elements of the tuple `inout` to anything. If you just want to swap elements, why not just say

```
(Ints.first, Ints.second) = (Ints.second, Ints.first)
```

**EDIT** But the issue can be reproduced only on the command line, not in an iOS project, and as Martin R points out in a comment, this doesn't seem to be a case of simultaneous access at all. I have filed a bug report.

**EDIT2** My bug report came back as not being a bug. Global tuples really *are* different from local tuples.

**EDIT3** The situation has completely changed in beta 5, where the test code doesn't even compile; the exclusive access problem is now caught up front.

Comment: And in any case it's hard to see what would be wrong with passing the whole tuple and letting the value type give you safety. It's not like it's heavyweight... :)

Comment: SE-0176 states: *"Accesses to different stored properties of a struct or different elements of a tuple are allowed to overlap."* so this actually may be a compiler bug.

Comment: @MartinR In any case the difference between the command-line and an iOS project in Xcode is a bug. — I also have a bug filed on the case where we access multiple different elements of an array simultaneously: if `components` is an array, I can't call `c.getRed(&components[0], green: &components[1], blue: &components[2], alpha: &components[3])`, and I don't see why not.

Comment: The difference seems to be if the tuple is a global variable or not (instead of iOS vs command-line). `var tuple = (1, 2); swap(&tuple.0, &tuple.1)` works as expected inside a function, but crashes on top-level. – Do you have a bug number for those who want to follow the issue?

Comment: @MartinR In general this turns out not to be a bug. Globals are different.

Comment: @MartinR Check out beta 5, where things are quite different.