# Swift4: why and when is simultaneous access to separate struct elements illegal?

Tags: swift4

Similar to the situation in [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559168/swift-4-simultaneous-access-to-tuple-members-as-inout) ,

> I am getting *run-time errors* *(Swift 4.2 Xcode 10.0) for
>   attempting "**simultaneous access**" in an object method to two separate
>   members of a single instance struct.*

If I attempt the same type of access to two separate instance members (which, conceptually, are also two separate members of a single different instance struct: the object itself; i.e. self), there is no problem. Can anyone help me understand the condition I am violating and why it exists?

```
import Cocoa

struct SomeStruct {
 var a:Int = 0
 var b:Int = 0
}

func writeTwoValues(first:inout Int, second:inout Int) {
 first = 1
 second = 2
}

@NSApplicationMain class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

 fileprivate var someStruct = SomeStruct() // Instance struct of ints

 var c:Int = 0  // Instance ints not inside a struct
 var d:Int = 0

 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

      writeTwoValues(first: &c, second: &d)   // Works great

      writeTwoValues(first: &someStruct.a, second: &someStruct.b)
     // Fails at runtime with "Simultaneous accesses..., but modification requires exclusive access
 }
}
```

The accepted responder to the quoted question above writes that exclusive access is designed "to prevent you exactly from doing what you're trying to do" in this access pattern. But the *WWDC video* and *SE-0176* only contain examples in which the same piece of memory is aliased by two different references. I understand why these are problematic. In the code above, however, as in the quoted query, the two references target separate and non-overlapping memory locations in all runtime execution paths. We never have two simultaneous io accesses to the same memory, or to overlapping pieces of memory (such as a member and the struct that contains it). So why is this a design and runtime error?

(I understand it's trivial to rewrite these examples if you have access to the struct definitions and to the methods that take io parameters. If you are accessing a fixed API, your options are fewer. I'm more interested in understanding why Swift rejects this code, and where the precise border of legal code falls than in figuring out how to get my sample here to run differently.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly state, in practice there is no conflicting access in your code. The question is whether Swift recognises that or plays safe.

Turning to *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2)*, which is as close as we can get to a formal definition of Swift we find in the *Memory Safety* chapter:

> **Conflicting Access to Properties**
>
> Types like structures, tuples, and enumerations are made up of individual constituent values, such as the properties of a structure or the elements of a tuple. Because these are value types, mutating any piece of the value mutates the whole value, meaning read or write access to one of the properties requires read or write access to the whole value.

Here you can read "Because  these are value types" as "In Swift it was decided that for composite values type", i.e. Apple made a choice and defined things this way, other languages might make other choices.

So by that statement your code is conflicting. However a few paragraphs later an Apple writes about relaxing this specification:

> In practice, most access to the properties of a structure can overlap safely.
>
> *[An example similar to yours except it uses a local variable]*
>
> The compiler can prove that memory safety is preserved because the two stored properties don’t interact in any way.

So Apple is saying in the case of *local* variables the compiler can determine there is no overlapping access and relax the restriction that access to any member is treated as access to the whole.

But you are using an *instance* variable of a *class*. A few paragraphs later Apple states:

> Specifically, it can prove that overlapping access to properties of a structure is safe if the following conditions apply:
>
> - You’re accessing only stored properties of an instance, not computed properties or class properties.
> - The structure is the value of a local variable, not a global variable.
> - The structure is either not captured by any closures, or it’s captured only by nonescaping closures.

And from your code we can say that it appears ", not a global variable" here is not exhaustive, it means anything other than "a local variable".

Of course I say *it appears* here as we all know that Swift is a loosely defined moving target and its compiler and semantics will probably be different next Tuesday ;-)

HTH

Comment: I appreciate the clear and well-sourced answer; and specifically to your cited emphasis on the copy-on-write semantics of structs. That clarifies why an io reference even to a single element needs to be thought of as a ref to the entire struct, leading to why two io references to separate elements in fact _do_ naively overlap (at least without additional compilation smarts to manage them safely).